# Understanding the ? notation for Java

Tags: java, notation

I came across a code snippet online that used a notation that from what I gather seems to do a comparison and then returns back possible multiple outputs. I am still confused about it, even after research. Can someone re-write the code snippet to an equivalent, more basic version so that I can make sure I am understanding what I am seeing?

```
int mPart = i < mParts.length ? Integer.parseInt(mParts[i]) : 0;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F: This is not exclusive to java. it's used in MANY languages.

Comment: Awww, yes this is what I wanted to know.

Comment: I even don't know which point in "close" menu to select for this question...

Comment: You couldn't just google `java question mark`....?

Comment: @Reimeus too fast for me :)

Comment: I did. Examples work better for me. When I can see the equivalent in a different context, instead of reading an explanation. Sorry I do not learn same as you.

Comment: @portfoliobuilder Nearly every single page that turns up as a result for that google search shows examples...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ternary IF operator. This line is equal to

```
int mPart;
if(i < mParts.length) {
   mPart = Integer.parseInt(mParts[i]);
} else {
   mPart = 0;
}
```

Comment: With the additional bonus that in the case of the ternary operator you can make 'mPart' final

Comment: It's the _conditional operator_ which is a _ternary operator._ There is no "ternary if" operator.

Comment: Even still, he introduced to me a new term. I had not learned of ternary yet. I will accept this answer when I can.